# XCode 32-bit not able to set 8bytes alignment?

Tags: xcode, memory-alignment

I tried to build my windows source code in XCode6.4. But find alignment issue.
I set 8 bytes alignment by"#pragma pack(x)" as windows default, but seems not work.

XCode only accept 1, 2, 4, but if set to 8, still same with 4.

Is this XCode bug?
Following are my code.

```
#pragma pack(8)
typedef struct
{
    char cField;
    double dField;
}ppkStructure; 

int nSize = sizeof(ppkStructure);
```

I know I can use **attribute** ((aligned (8))), but that's NOT the solution. I have thousands structure need to change if do so.

Answer (score 0):

If I set pack(1), nSize is 9, 
set pack(2), nSize is 10
set pack(4), nSize is 12 
set pack(8), nSize is 12 still. Same as pack(4). No as expected value: 16.